# Join between three tables to find the places visited by friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables made ​​in this way:

**users**

> | *id* | username | img |

the primary key is id but username is a unique key

**maps**

> | *id* | username | address |

the primary key is id.
Contains various maps (city) users who have visited.

**friend**

> | *id* | user_req | user_acc | status |

the primary key is id.
Two users are friends only if the status is 1.

---

I need to have as a result the maps that my friends have, so a tuple like this:

> | username | img | address |

*username* is the username of my friend

*img* is the image of her profile

*address* is the address, the place he has visited

Tuples must also be sorted in descending order according to the id of maps table.

The query I used to find the friends of a user is:

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN friend ON (username = user_req) 
        WHERE (user_acc = ? AND status = 1) 
        UNION DISTINCT 
        SELECT * 
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN friend ON (username = user_acc) 
        WHERE (user_req = ? AND status = 1)
```

where **?** is the user I want to find friends.

Does anyone know how to do? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Extra join to maps?

```
SELECT u.username, u2.img, m.address
FROM friend f 
INNER JOIN users u ON f.user_acc = u.username
INNER JOIN maps m ON u.username = m.username
WHERE (f.user_req = ? AND f.status = 1) 
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT u.username, u2.img, m.address
FROM friend f 
INNER JOIN users u ON f.user_req = u.username
INNER JOIN maps m ON u.username = m.username
WHERE (f.user_acc = ? AND f.status = 1) 
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! When I run your query, I get the following error **Table 'u' doesn't exist**. When I replace u with users, I have a problem on u2.. :(

Comment: Errr, oops. Meant to alias the users table as u. Put the u in but forgot to mention users. Fixed now.